# MySQL query to meet specific needs

Tags: mysql

My table is as follow:

```
-------------------------------------------
| rec_id | A_id  | B_id  |Date(YYYY-MM-DD)|
-------------------------------------------
| 1      | 1     | 6     | 2014-01-01     |
| 2      | 5     | 1     | 2014-01-02     |
| 3      | 2     | 6     | 2015-01-03     |
| 4      | 6     | 1     | 2014-01-04     |
| 5      | 7     | 1     | 2014-01-05     |
| 6      | 3     | 6     | 2014-01-06     |
| 7      | 8     | 1     | 2014-01-07     |
| 8      | 4     | 6     | 2014-01-08     |
| 9      | 9     | 1     | 2014-01-09     |
| 10     | 10    | 21    | 2014-01-10     |
| 11     | 12    | 21    | 2014-01-11     |
| 12     | 11    | 2     | 2014-01-12     |
| 13     | 1     | 1     | 2014-12-31     |
| 14     | 2     | 2     | 2014-12-31     |
| 15     | 1     | 1     | 2015-01-31     |
| 16     | 10    | 21    | 2015-01-31     |
| 17     | 1     | 21    | 2014-10-31     |
```

This table represents the possession of various "A_id" to a specific "B_id" with a date when it is possessed. The possession of each "A_id" can be changed later on at any time. That means the only the latest possession is considered.

I want to find out all the "A_id" that are currently (possessed in latest date) in possession of a specific "B_id". For example, for "B_id" = 6 the possessed "A_id" at present are as follows:

```
---------------------------
| A_id | Date(YYYY-MM-DD) |
---------------------------
| 2    | 2015-01-03       |
| 3    | 2014-01-06       |
| 4    | 2014-01-08       |
```

Similarly, for "B_id" = 21 the possessed "A_id" at present are as follows:

```
---------------------------
| A_id | Date(YYYY-MM-DD) |
---------------------------
| 10   | 2015-01-31       |
| 12   | 2014-01-11       |
```

I would highly appreciate your kind help in this regard.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code generation service. What did you tried? What is the **specific** problem with your query? Please read [ask] in [help]!

Comment: I am a newbie in mysql. Still I have tried hard with my limited knowledge. But failed to produce the exact query. That's why I have asked for help from genius like you in this regard.

Comment: You can share your queries when they are not perfect too. In most cases, it helps to understand the problem and the way you tried to solve it. Also it shows some effort, and improves the chance of getting better answers. Do not be shy, it is OK, if you are new to any technology and it is also fine to ask if you do not understand or know something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use a correlated `not exists` predicate that makes sure that there doesn't exists any later possession for each A_ID with another B_ID.

```
SELECT A_ID, MAX(PDATE) AS DATE 
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
WHERE B_ID = 6
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
    WHERE A_ID = T.A_ID 
      AND PDATE > T.PDATE 
      AND B_ID <> T.B_ID
    )
GROUP BY A_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @jpw. But, I am having "Unknown column `T.DATE` at where clause" error.

Comment: @mbk Is the column not named `date`? I assumed it was. If it's called something else you have to adjust the query to match your table design.

Comment: the column name is 'pDate'. I have adjusted, but the error still exists.

Comment: @mbk Does the query you're trying look exactly like the one in my answer? The query works, see this example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/294449

Comment: Thanks. It is working perfectly. Can you help me in another query? I want find out the total number of 'A_id' for each 'B_id'.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please consider accepting it. And the other query should be: "select b_id, count(distinct a_id) as a_count from your_table group by b_id"

Comment: This would count the number of distinct a_id for every b_id, if you want duplicates too just remove the distinct keyword.